# ROS2 in google cloud robotics

Tags: google-cloud-robotics

I would like to ask if it is possible to use or has the ros2 already been used with cloud robotics?

I am currently developing a project using cloud robotics, and one of the goals is to use ros2 to send orders to the robot.

My question is how to send orders to the robot remotely using ros2 in k8s.

If someone can give me some reference it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to use ROS2 to communicate between the cloud and the robot, I'm afraid it won't help. You could consider using a declarative API to reliably send orders from the cloud to the robot. You'd need to:

- create a custom resource definition (CRD) to represent your orders
- send orders from the cloud by creating a custom resource
- create a controller on the robot, which looks at the orders and executes them

There's more detail in the [declarative API tutorial](https://googlecloudrobotics.github.io/core/how-to/creating-declarative-api.html).

If you want to avoid this indirection and use ROS2, [this ROS forum post](https://answers.ros.org/question/286788/ros2-remote-node-setup/) suggests using a VPN that can forward multicast traffic.